# Controller in a UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have several controllers linked to a TabBar controller.
Each time I switch from one tab to another, the previous controller is shown. I thought that when I select a tab, a new controller is built and its new view shown. Is it possible to have this behaviour rather than the one showing the view like it was when it was hidden ?

Comment: Do you mean switching tabs and updating the UI of the newly presented VC?

Comment: Yes. I thought that after switching from one tab to another, a new VC is instatiate (and so a new view). When leaving this tab, I was thinking that the VC is discarded. It seems that I am wrong on this since the views remain exactly like they were before switching. Do you agree ?

Comment: The views are stored in memory until a memory warning is given and then they're released. UIKit will deal with that side of it for you.

Comment: Why do you need to completely re instantiate VC? You can just reload it's view or data. Btw UITabbarController don't support this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question with a little bit of detail, you could utilise the viewDidAppear method. That way you get to update your UI as well as not reloading the viewController causing possible memory issues.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // all UI items will be changed here upon the first instantiation of the viewController.
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("loaded FirstViewController viewDidLoad()")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // reload your UI elements here if you want and update between switching viewControllers.
    print("loaded FirstViewController viewDidAppear()")
}
```

In the old days there was a method of `viewDidUnload`, however according to the Apple documentation:

> Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this
>   method is never called.

You could use the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` but when it comes to view controllers I'd let UIKit and ARC do it's job and release the VC when needed.

Comment: thks. And how do I reload the UI ? (it 's a split View). I want the detail view collapsed and the tableView scrolled to the top.

Comment: You could update the UI in the competition block of your network requests etc. It depends on what's updating what.